# Unable to create a C# console application in VS Code terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When I try to create a new C# project in VScode,I got aerror. How can I fix it?

This is my command:

`PS C:\Users\lau\Documents\code\c#> dotnet new console`

And this is the error message：

> Template "Console Application" could not be created. Error while 
>   processing file
>   /content/ConsoleApplication-CSharp/Company.ConsoleApplication1.csproj
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\lau\Documents\code\c#\c#.csproj'. File name:
>   'C:\Users\lau\Documents\code\c#\c#.csproj'    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
>   share, FileOptions options)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)    at
>   System.IO.File.Create(String path)    at
>   Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.CreateFile(String
>   path)    at
>   Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Core.Util.Orchestrator.ProcessFile(IFile
>   sourceFile, String sourceRel, String targetDir, IGlobalRunSpec spec,
>   IProcessor fallback, IEnumerable`1 fileGlobProcessors, IReadOnlyList`1
>   locOperations)

Comment: Is your 'C:\Users\lau\Documents\code\c#' directory empty?

Comment: Yeah, it's empty

Comment: try to use other name than c# for your root folder  /hello>dotnet new console
.Or you have rights problems on that folder

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, I fixed mine by opening the command prompt console as an administrator

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and fixed it creating directory again from `root` or creating directory in `C:\`, the problem is permissions associated to directory

Answer (score 1):

**I fixed it.** I had same problem and settings-windows security-protected folders-(user account control (YES))-allow this folders (for in ../../console folder). again create folder --> dotnet new console (created successfully)